# The log file contains the log statements with message stamp as shown below

Tags: awk, logfile

The log file contains the log statements with message stamp as shown below.
The utility lists out all the actions that took more than the specified time. The time is specified in seconds from the command line.

Input:

```
#<process id> <date time> <log level> <file name> <line number> <actual message>

1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 WARN db_util.c 5928 Config file not found, using default values
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:17 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connected to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:17 ERROR log_test.c 198 Unable to setup our satellite launch system
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:21 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnected. Initialize to launch the satellite
```

Eg: If the utility is executed by giving the input file as input and 2 seconds the performance threshold time, it should produce this output:

```
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite.
```

I have found this code working for the above mentioned problem statement:

```
awk -v threshold=$1 '{texttime=mktime(gensub(/-|:/," ", "g", $2" "$3))} NR>1 && texttime-prevtexttime>threshold{print prevrecord} {prevtexttime=texttime; prevrecord=$0}' $2
```

Is there any more elegant way of converting the current record's date and time to a unix timestamp? Other than this `(mktime(gensub(/-|:/," ", "g", $2" "$3)))`

Answer (score 0):

With awk? Not really (just change `/-|:/` to `/[-:]/`). I believe perl has `strptime()` which would save you one function call for the equivalent code but IMHO it's not worth changing tools/languages just for that.

Comment: Thank You Ed Morton for your reply. What is the other way without using awk?